# Where can i find the debug information in zuul?

Tags: netflix-zuul

I want to use debugFilter in ZUUL. when i post param "debug=true" in query string, I can't find the debug info in my standard output.

Where can i find the debug information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call api with param `debug=true`, debugging information will be accumulated into `RequestContext` with a key `routingDebug`. The value is `List<String>` type.
If you set the properties like below, debug info will be added into response-header - `X-Zuul-Debug-Header`.

```
zuul.include-debug-header=true
```

As far as I know, this information is not printed out to standard out as default. 
Instead, you can easily access this info via `com.netflix.zuul.context.Debug.getRoutingDebug()`.

You can make your own post filter to print out this info easily like below.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return Debug.debugRouting();
}

@Override
public Object run() {
    String debug = convertToPrettyPrintString(Debug.getRoutingDebug());
    log.info("Filter Debug Info = \n{}", debug);
    // or System.out.println(...)
    return null;
}

private String convertToPrettyPrintString(List<String> filterDebugList) {
    return filterDebugList.stream()
        .map(s -> s.startsWith("{") ? "\t" + s : s)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

Comment: It should work. Did you add `?debug=true` in your request ? Please refer to this link : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1691